# Как конвертировать длинное str число в float?

Tags: python, float

Суть в том, что я получаю строчку с нужным мне числом(str), но когда его преобразовываю в float мне возвращает что-то непонятное

```
money = 0.0
money += float('{:.8f}'.format(float('0.00000049')))
print(money)
```

> Вывод 4.9e-07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да всё у вас нормально, это вопрос представления числа, а не его хранения:

```
money = 0.0
money += float('{:.8f}'.format(float('0.00000049')))
print(f'{money:.8f}') # я задал формат при печати
```

Вывод:

```
0.00000049
```

Я, правда, не очень понимаю, зачем вы строку преобразовываете во `float`, потом обратно в строку и потом обратно во `float` ещё раз. Или вы думали, что именно это "ломает" число? Нет, число остаётся как было, просто по умолчанию маленькие числа, у которых много нулей после запятой, печатаются в "научной нотации", в вашем случае - как `4.9 * 10**-7`, если не указано другое. При указании формата с фиксированной точкой вы тут же видите привычное вам число.